# dropdownlist of Country display name and codes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone either show me a an example or a tutorial that shows a dropdownlist of countries and their codes
my code shows the wrong language codes for New Zealand it displays mi-NZ instead of en-NZ

ASP.NET

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     {

    SortedDictionary<string, string> objDic = 
           new SortedDictionary<string, string>();                     

    foreach (CultureInfo ObjectCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))         
    {            
        RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjectCultureInfo.Name);             
        if(!objDic.ContainsKey(objRegionInfo.EnglishName)) {                     
            objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.EnglishName, ObjectCultureInfo.Name); 
        }         
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in objDic)
    {              
        ddlCountries.Items.Add(new ListItem(val.Key, val.Value));         
    }   

}
```

e.g

```
United States(en-US)
New Zealand(en-NZ)
China(zh-CN)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are excluding `RegionInfo.EnglishName`, remove the `!` and try `CultureTypes.AllCultures`:

```
foreach (CultureInfo ObjectCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))         
{            
    RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjectCultureInfo.Name); 
    if(objDic.ContainsKey(objRegionInfo.EnglishName)) {                     
        objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.EnglishName, ObjectCultureInfo.Name); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: See update, I was only looking at your logic before. Also, don't be rude here, you came here with a problem people are willing to help you with for nothing in return.

Comment: Thanks for that sorry dude. Hey would you be able to answer this question i posted about changing the language on postback  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642304/how-do-change-the-language-not-changing-on-postback