# Why doesn't the language change on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, webforms

My dropdownlist has a list of languages with values in the form of en-NZ, en-US etc but the page doesn't change the language on postback is my language codes wrong. Could someone have a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong to change the language for my page

And my lbllanguage.Text changes on the second postback aswell so it's suppose to change on the ChangeLanguage_Click event first time it is clicked

Main Page:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Culture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
    if (ddlChangeLanguage.Items.FindByValue(Culture) != null)
    {
        ddlChangeLanguage.SelectedValue = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture; 
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<CultureInfo> languages = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

        SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedLanguages = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (CultureInfo language in languages)
        {
            RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(language.Name);
            if (!sortedLanguages.ContainsKey(regionInfo.EnglishName))
            {
                sortedLanguages.Add(regionInfo.EnglishName, language.Name);
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> language in sortedLanguages)
        {
            ddlChangeLanguage.Items.Add(new ListItem { Value = language.Value, Text = language.Key });
        }
        ddlChangeLanguage.SelectedValue = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
    }
    lbllanguage.Text = this.UICulture;

}

protected void ChangeLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture = ddlChangeLanguage.SelectedValue;
}
```

and my BasePage which my main page inherits

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
    }

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {            
        this.Culture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
        this.UICulture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store your strings in a resource file or satellite assemblies for translations to happen:

[ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1Caption %>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure the current thread too:

```
var culture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: I tried that and I had to make it Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture) and it still didn't work am i missing something in my Web.config I don't understand this

Comment: you changed your page's and thread's CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture, right?

Comment: I changed the Culture and UICulture but the english text doesn't change to the other language so if i have text that says "Hello World" it still displays "Hello World" not in the the language specified

Comment: Wait, you are expecting .NET to translate the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the logic in Page_PreRender to a handler for DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: My real issue at the moment is trying to change the language for the page. The Page_PreRender event is needed to automaticaly select the Profiles Preferences property on postback I tried todo what you said but it doesn't make any difference to change my language for the page

Comment: in the page_load is HttpContext.Current.Profile returing what expected?

Comment: Yeah it must be because on Pre_Render it selects the ddlChangeLanguage.SelectedValue

Comment: Just to confirm. It's like a chat based debugging :P. Ok, it seems you need to configure the culture of the current thread.

Comment: Im not getting anywhere. Its not changing the language it sets the UICulture and Culture but the text isn't changin the language